# Template argument type deduction by conversion operator

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, operator-overloading, type-deduction

I see example from the C++ 11 Standard (n3337, 14.8.2.3/7)

```
struct A {
template <class T> operator T***();
};
A a;
const int * const * const * p1 = a; // T is deduced as int, not const int
```

and try to reproduce it by different compilers. I changed the example a little by adding a declaration with type T in a conversion function

```
struct A {
    template <class T> operator T***()
    {
        T t;  //if T==const int, then it is error (uninitialized const)
        return nullptr;
    }
};
A a;
const int * const * const * p1 = a;

int main(){}
```

All the compilers (VS2014, gcc 5.1.0 and clang 3.5.1) give an error in the declaration of "t", which means T is deduced as const int. Why is that? Is it some extension?

Comment: Congratulations, you found a compiler bug. (This is not a conforming extension; it rejects code that is well-formed according to the standard.)

Comment: @T.C. Just [reported](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=66108) it. Too bad bugzilla doesn't let you ninja-edit commits!

Comment: Amazingly. As many as 3 compilers have same bug :) P.S. icc 13.0.1 compilers ok

Comment: @user3514538 As mentioned in my answer, a developer of EDG filed the defect report. The intel compiler employs the EDG frontend; that explains why it's the only conforming implementation here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This was covered by [**CWG issue #349**](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#349), opened by a developer of the [EDG C++ front end](https://www.edg.com/index.php?location=c_frontend) (which apparently deduces `int`, not `const int`):

> We ran into an issue concerning qualification conversions when doing
>   template argument deduction for conversion functions.
>
> The question is: What is the type of T in the conversion functions
>   called by this example? Is T "int" or "const int"?
>
> If T is "int", the conversion function in class A works and the one in
>   class B fails (because the return expression cannot be converted to
>   the return type of the function). If T is "const int", A fails and B
>   works.
>
> Because the qualification conversion is performed on the result of the
>   conversion function, I see no benefit in deducing T as const int.
>
> In addition, I think the code in class A is more likely to occur than
>   the code in class B. If the author of the class was planning on
>   returning a pointer to a const entity, I would expect the function to
>   have been written with a const in the return type.
>
> Consequently, I believe the correct result should be that T is int.
>
> ```
> struct A {
>   template <class T> operator T***() {
>       int*** p = 0;
>       return p;
>   }
> };
>
> struct B {
>   template <class T> operator T***() {
>       const int*** p = 0;
>       return p;
>   }
> };
>
> int main()
> {
>   A a;
>   const int * const * const * p1 = a;
>   B b;
>   const int * const * const * p2 = b;
> }
> ```
>
> We have just implemented this feature, and pending clarification by the committee, we deduce T as int. **It appears that g++ and the Sun compiler deduce T as const int.**

This only brought the quoted paragraph into existence (it didn't exist in C++03!), and was presumably overlooked by compiler developers.