# templated conversion operator type deduction differs in clang and gcc

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, clang++, type-deduction

I've been fighting differences between compilers with respect to templated conversion operator type deduction for the past few days, and I've finally boiled down at least one of the differences to a stack-overflow-sized example:

```
void foo(int i);

struct any_const_reference {
  template <typename T>
  operator const T&();
};

template <typename T, typename Enable=void>
struct detect_call : std::false_type { };

template <typename T>
struct detect_call<T,
  decltype( declval<T>()( any_const_reference() ) )
> : std::true_type { };
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/558fb054be462cfb)

The expression `detect_call<decltype(foo)>::value` give `true` in clang and `false` in gcc (using any modern version of either compiler that I can get my hands on, the latest being gcc 5.2 and clang 3.8).  Questions:

- Which is correct?  That is, which conforms to the C++ standard?
- What is causing this difference?
- In general, what are the type deduction rules being applied to `T` in the conversion operator (or in any conversion operator of this form, e.g., `template <typename T> operator T();`), and where are they given in the C++ standard?

Note: this seems to be similar to this question: [Template argument type deduction by conversion operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30172533/template-argument-type-deduction-by-conversion-operator) (indeed, I've run into that exact difference as well), but I don't quite see the mapping between that answer and this case.  If this is just another instance of this issue, then this question boils down to how to map that issue into this use case.

Comment: Looks like https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=63217

Comment: can you put in a complete example in your code and also put what version of gcc and clang you're testing with, to make this easier to find for other people finding this bug?

Comment: @xaxxon the complete example is in the Demo link, but it's basically what's given there with some #includes and a main that invokes the expression given in the question.  I added compiler versions for posterity

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be simplified to just actually calling `foo()`:

```
void foo(int ) { }

struct any_const_reference {
  template <typename T>
  operator const T&();
};

int main() {
    foo(any_const_reference{}); // ok on clang
                                // error on gcc
}
```

This is a gcc bug ([#63217](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=63217) per TC's comment above). Per [[temp.deduct.conv]](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.deduct.conv), this should deduce `T` as `int` since both the reference and qualifiers should be removed (in this case `P` is `const T&` and `A` is `int`).

Comment: Thanks.  [temp.deduct.conv] is exactly what I was looking for but couldn't find.